# RxJS withLatestFrom skips initial Subject value

Tags: rxjs

In the following example, for whatever reason, initial value is ignored.

```
const frameRateSubject: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(24);
const loadedMetadata$: Observable<Event> = fromEvent(this.videoElement, 'loadedmetadata');

frameRateSubject.asObservable()
  .pipe(
    withLatestFrom(loadedMetadata$), // by commenting out this line, both 24 and 20 values are received
    tap(([frameRate]: [number, Event]) => {
      // initial value of 24 is never received, why is it?
      console.log('frameRateSubject', frameRate)
    })
  )
  .subscribe();

setTimeout(() => {
  frameRateSubject.next(20)
}, 10000)
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`withLatestFrom` combines the source observable (here `frameRateSubject$`) with other streams (`loadedMetadata$`) and emits values calculated from the latest values of each, **only when the source emits**.

But in your case `loadedMetadata$` hasn't emitted when `frameRateSubject$` emits `24`. So the value is skipped.

`CombineLatest` is most likely the operator you are looking for here.

Comment: You are right. I already found this [marble diagram](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/withLatestFrom/) for this operator. Use of combineLatest was exactly the solution. Thanks for help